# rsync: tips for sending a very large file?

Tags: rsync

I have a very large database dump file (80GB) and I want to rsync it.

I'm starting with this command:

```
$ rsync -av --stats db.dump me@XX.XX.XX.XX:/webapps
```

But is there anything else I should do to improve the chances of this massive file being transferred successfully?

Comment: Add the following options: `-z` will use compression in transit. This is useful for over the wire transfer. `-S` will handle sparse file efficiently. This is good if your large file is a sparse file. `-u` will skip unchanged files. `-H` will preserve hard links. Use if you expect some files to be hard links.

Comment: @alvits thank you! do submit as an answer if you like!